# How to use count,'like' and group by in single query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-aggregation

I need something like

```
SELECT sum(case when name LIKE 'nick-1%' then 1 end) as Count,
       name 
FROM dummytable 
GROUP BY CASE 
           WHEN name LIKE 'nick-1%' THEN 'nick' 
           WHEN name LIKE 'vicky-1%' THEN 'vicky' 
           ELSE NULL 
         END
```

```
Name  Count
nick    10
vicky   17
```

nick means it should contain name like 'nick%'
vicky means it should contain name like 'vicky%'

In my query I cant able to view name column since using sum it ask me to add it to group by but I cant able to add it to group by since I am using like function for it

Comment: In my query i cant able to view name column since using sum it ask me to add it to group by but i cant able to add it to group by since i am using like function for it

Comment: Your query does not make complete sense to me.  Can you show us sample data from `dummytable` and your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve the problem you are having, you only need to repeat the same `CASE` expression you currently have in your `GROUP BY` in your `SELECT` as well:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN name LIKE 'nick-1%'  THEN 'nick'
            WHEN name LIKE 'vicky-1%' THEN 'vicky'
            ELSE NULL END AS Name,
       COUNT(*) AS Count
FROM dummytable
GROUP BY CASE WHEN name LIKE 'nick-1%'  THEN 'nick'
              WHEN name LIKE 'vicky-1%' THEN 'vicky'
              ELSE NULL END
```

In your original query, you were mixing two types of aggregation.  If you want to use conditional aggregation over the entire table, which you original `SELECT` was trying to do, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT 'nick' AS Name, SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'nick-1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Count
FROM dummytable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'vicky', SUM(CASE WHEN name LIKE 'vicky-1%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM dummytable
```